# Nunit database rollback

Tags: database, nunit, integration-testing

I'm fairly new to using Nunit as a test framework and have come across something I don't really understand.

I am writing an integration test which inserts a row into a database table. As I want to repeatedly run this test I wanted to delete the row out once the test has completed. The test runs fine, however when I look in the database table the row in question is still there even though the delete command ran. I can even see it run when profiling the database whilst running the test.

Does Nunit somehow rollback database transaction? If anyone has any ideas why I am seeing this happen please let me know. I have been unable to find any information about Nunit rolling back transactions which makes me think I'm doing something wrong, but the test runs the row appears in the database it is just not being deleted afterwards even though profiler shows the command being run!

Here is the test code I am running

```
    [Test]
    [Category("Consultant split integration test")]
    public void Should_Save_Splits()
    {
        var splitList = new List<Split>();

        splitList.Add(new Split()
        {
            UnitGroupId = 69,
            ConsultantUserId = 1,
            CreatedByUserId = 1,
            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
            UpdatedByUserId = 1,
            UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now,
            Name = "Consultant1",
            Unit = "Unit1",
            Percentage = 100,
            PlacementId = 47
        });

        var connection = Helpers.GetCpeDevDatabaseConnection();
        var repository = new Placements.ConsultantSplit.DAL.PronetRepository();
        var notebookManager = Helpers.GetNotebookManager(connection);
        var userManager = Helpers.GetUserManager(connection);
        var placementManager = Helpers.GetPlacementManager(connection);
        var sut = new Placements.ConsultantSplit.ConsultantSplitManager(repository, connection, notebookManager, userManager, placementManager);

        IEnumerable<string> errors;
        sut.SaveSplits(splitList, out errors);

        try
        {
            using (connection.Connection)
            {
                using (
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from ConsultantSplit where placementid=47",
                        connection.Connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    connection.UseTransaction = false;
                    cmd.Transaction = connection.Transaction;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            throw new Exception(exp.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Not an answer for you, but NUnit does nothing with database transactions unless you are using some third-party addon that does rollbacks. In any case, if there were a rollback, both the add and the delete would likely be rolled back.